# OrderBy IEnumerable property of class

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Given the following class, I would like to sort a list first by the FirstName property, and then by the PetNames property:

```
private class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> PetNames { get; set; }
}
```

Ordering the list by just the FirstName works fine:

```
//...snip...//

people.OrderBy(a => a.FirstName);

//...snip...//
```

But I am having difficulty sorting the list based on the PetNames property as well:

```
people.OrderBy(a => a.FirstName)
      .ThenBy(a => a.PetNames);
```

This results in an exception:

> EntityCommandCompilationException was unhandled by user code

EDIT:

What I meant to explain is that I am trying to first sort the list the FirstName property, and then sort the list of values in the PetNames property.  For example:

```
FirstName---LastName---PetNames
Jim---------Jones------{Rex, Fido}
Bob---------Smith------{Pluto, Goofy}
```

when sorted, would turn into:

```
FirstName---LastName---PetNames
Bob---------Smith------{Goofy, Pluto}
Jim---------Jones------{Fido, Rex}
```

Any help on how to fix this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How is this supposed to work? How do you sort by a list of values? e.g., which comes first out of {4, 7, 23}, {2, 16, 1} and {6, 22, 9}?

Comment: Ah, I apologize for the confusion... and I see why the .ThenBy will not work in this case.  I'll edit my question to reflect what I'm truly after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to convert `PetNames` to a value that Linq-to-Entities can compare it by. Maybe something like this:

```
people.OrderBy(a => a.FirstName)
    .ThenBy(a => String.Join("", a.PetNames.ToArray()));
```

**UPDATE:**
According to your question clarification:

```
people.Select(p => new Person()
{
    FirstName = p.FirstName,
    LastName = p.LastName,
    DateOfBirth = p.DateOfBirth,
    PetNames = p.PetNames.OrderBy(n => n)
})
.OrderBy(a => a.FirstName);
```

Comment: This returns the following exception: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.String[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @Sesame - My mistake. Linq-to-Entities doesn't support the `String.Join` method. I updated the answer according to your edit.

Comment: Note that this duplicates every `Person` instance which may cause unexpected behaviour if you're expecting to be sorting a list of references to the same objects.

Comment: @AntP - Since the `Select` is still connected to the context, it wouldn't duplicate the instance, just generate the SELECT in Sql.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do the PetNames sort operation, in get (or could be set) part of the property in your Person class;

```
public class Person
{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    // Do the sort order of the pet names while you get the value
    IEnumerable<string> petNames = new HashSet<string>();
    public IEnumerable<string> PetNames
    {
        get { return petNames.OrderBy(p => p); }
        set { petNames = value; } // Or sorting could be done in set as well
    }
}
```

Then again;

```
people.OrderBy(a => a.FirstName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit, the only way I can think to do this with a single lambda expression (and not just using a simple `foreach` for the pet names first) is to do this:

```
people.Select(p => { p.PetNames = p.PetNames.OrderBy(o => o); return p; })
      .OrderBy(p => p.FirstName);
```

But I don't really see what's wrong with just doing:

```
foreach(var person in people)
{
    person.PetNames = person.PetNames.OrderBy(o => o);
}

var sorted = people.OrderBy(p => p.FirstName);
```

I'm sure there probably is an elegant way of writing this in one lambda expression that doesn't use an explicit anonymous function like that but I'm having trouble coming up with it so I imagine it would be pretty cryptic.