# Group students with similar scores (5 points up/ down)

Tags: c#, linq

I want to group students with similar scores with 5 points up/ down.

```
public class Students
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Marks {get; set;}
    public int GroupID {get; set;}
}

public static void Main()
{
    List<Students> students = new List<Students>();
    
    students.Add(new Students { Name = "Aakash", Marks=89, GroupID=0 });
    students.Add(new Students { Name = "Prakash", Marks=85, GroupID=0  });
    students.Add(new Students { Name = "Ramesh", Marks=40, GroupID=0  });
    students.Add(new Students { Name = "Neha", Marks=95, GroupID=0 });
    students.Add(new Students { Name = "Suresh", Marks=93, GroupID=0 });
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
GroupID 1:
Aakash, Prakash

Group 2:
Ramesh
    
GroupID 3:
Neha, Suresh
```

What happens when students with marks of 4, 8, 12, 16, 20 & 24?

They would be split into different groups so that each group has a range of 5 points difference at maximum:

- 4 & 8 in Group 1
- 12 & 16 in Group 2
- 20 & 24 in Group 3.

Comment: You need to explain what that actually means. What happens students with marks of 4, 8, 12, 16, 20 & 24? Is that one group or multiple? Vague descriptions are of little use because code must be exact. What are the exact rules?

Comment: @user18387401 No, they would be different groups like this- 4 & 8 in Group 1, 12 & 16 in Group 2 and 20 & 24 in Group 3.

Comment: So the grouping start from the lowest score, find any other members up to +5 score, and continue with the next?

Comment: @Martheen That's right

Comment: Then update your question with that definition. Seems rather straightforward with pre-ordering like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22700240/orderby-ienumerable-property-of-class and then just loop and put them in groups accordingly

Comment: So have you tried ordering and looping through it? Update your question with your effort, both in this and your previous question you simply dump your task without showing any effort.

Comment: you cant group them without having explicit and exclusive ranges like Group1={min=41, max=60}, Group2={min=61, max=70}, Group3={min=71, max=85}, Group4={min=86, max=100}; please include in your question if any.

Comment: It's very annoying when people just disregard what you say because it's too hard to think about. I asked you to explain the EXACT rules and you've made no effort to do that. If you can't explain the exact rules then you don't even understand the problem yourself, so what are you even asking about?

Comment: Apologies as I was away. I will try to improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to determine the range of marks for each group based on the *highest* mark in that group, you may write something like this:

```
var ordered = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.Marks).ToList();
int groupId = 0;
int nextIndex = 0;
while (nextIndex < ordered.Count)
{
    groupId++;
    var firstInGroup = ordered[nextIndex];
    var group = ordered.Skip(nextIndex).
                        TakeWhile(s => firstInGroup.Marks - s.Marks <= 5).ToList();
    group.ForEach(s => s.GroupID = groupId);
    nextIndex += group.Count;
}
```

To make this reusable and to allow grouping to happen in either direction, you can turn this into a helper method like so:

```
enum MarkGroupingOption { HighestToLowest, LowestToHighest }

static void SetGroupIds(List<Students> students, int marksThreshold, 
                        MarkGroupingOption groupingOption)
{
    var ordered = (groupingOption == MarkGroupingOption.HighestToLowest
        ? students.OrderByDescending(s => s.Marks).ToList()
        : students.OrderBy(s => s.Marks).ToList());

    int groupId = 0;
    int nextIndex = 0;
    while (nextIndex < ordered.Count)
    {
        groupId++;
        var firstInGroup = ordered[nextIndex];
        var remaining = ordered.Skip(nextIndex);
        var group = (groupingOption == MarkGroupingOption.HighestToLowest
            ? remaining.TakeWhile(s => firstInGroup.Marks - s.Marks <= marksThreshold)
            : remaining.TakeWhile(s => s.Marks - firstInGroup.Marks <= marksThreshold)
            ).ToList();
        group.ForEach(s => s.GroupID = groupId);
        nextIndex += group.Count;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
SetGroupIds(students, 5, MarkGroupingOption.HighestToLowest);

SetGroupIds(students, 5, MarkGroupingOption.LowestToHighest);
```